# presenting modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I have this:

```
SomeViewController* vc = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Blank black screen appears - how to fix it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late to the party here, but if you're initialising this modal view controller from a vc with a `UINavigationController`, try setting the modalPresentationStyle on the UINavigationController:

```
self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

that does not seem to be a valid initializer for a view controller. use – initWithNibName:bundle: if your subclass is a direct subclass of UIViewController

Comment: is your class a direct subclass of UIViewcontroller, or maybe UITableViewController? are you using the correct nib name?

Comment: UIViewcontroller or UITableViewController?

Comment: I think the problem might be nib name. Make sure your nib is being loaded correctly. There are other problems in your code. You are not setting up SomeViewController's modal presentation style, you are setting up self's modal presentation style, and self's view background color.